# Error /usr/bin/sgnonpluginprocess

Tags: error-handling, libgcrypt

I constantly receive these error messages, but I haven't found any solution yet in the WWW.
[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Does anyone know this issue?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be [a command from an Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=yakkety&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=sgnonpluginprocess). Did you install anything from source, or without using `apt-get`, the Software Centre, etc.?

Comment: yes, several, but this issue just appeared after a recent dist-upgrade. I have installed veracrypt by source, maybe here lies the issue?